# New Arduino project and empty folder in Project Explorer by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, arduino-c++

I've searched for some days and can't find anything about the solution of my problem. I'm trying to use Eclipse to develop arduino project, but I cannot create a new project. From Eclipse marketplacet I installed Eclispe C++ IDE for Arduino 3.0 plugin. I setted in Arduino Downloads Manager a Platform, and created a New Connection to Arduino. At the end of this process I tried to create a new project from File:"File → New → Project → C/C++ → Arduino Project - Arduino C++ Sketch". I fill up the properties of new Arduino project on the form and I push finish, Eclispe creates a new folder of the project but inside there is only .project file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Test</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cBuilder</name>
            <triggers>clean,full,incremental,</triggers>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.arduino.core.arduinoNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

If I create a new C++ project, Eclipse works well creating a project folder and all files and folders inside.
Can anyone help me to solve this bug? Maybe to understand how Eclipse build a project folder.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my configuration problem with another arduino ide plugin from eclipse marketplace. I downloaded:" The Arduino Eclipse plugin named Sloeber V4". This plugin runs well. I hope this information will be usefull.